# I want to display bar chart of 10 accounts with maximum contacts. each bar chart should be clickable and redirect to concerned account

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am able to show a bar chart using static data in vfp - apex. However there are mainly two problems - 1. getting dynamic data of no. of contacts in each account and 2. making each bar clickable and redirect to account

Tried making dynamic using following link- https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/building-dynamic-stacking-bar-charts-in-visualforce

Barchart help from - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm

Similar question on comminity related to click:- [showing each account with number of contact,if i click on contact count it has to direct to account detail page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119774/showing-each-account-with-number-of-contact-if-i-click-on-contact-count-it-has-t)

VF

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController">
<apex:chart height="400" width="700" data="{!data}">
  <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="data1" 
    title="Opportunities Closed" grid="true"/>
  <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" 
    title="Month of the Year">
</apex:axis>
<apex:barSeries axis="left"  xField="name" yField="data1" 
orientation="vertical" />
```

Controller code

```
 public class ChartController {

 // Return a list of data points for a chart
 public List<Data> getData() {
 return ChartController.getChartData();
 }

 // Make the chart data available via JavaScript remoting
 @RemoteAction
 public static List<Data> getRemoteData() {

 return ChartController.getChartData();
 //List<Account> accList=[select id,Name from account];
//return accList;
 }

 // The actual chart data; needs to be static to be
 // called by a @RemoteAction method
 public static List<Data> getChartData() {
 List<Account> accList=[select id,Name from account];
 List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
 data.add(new Data('Jan', 30 ));
 data.add(new Data('Feb', 44 ));
 data.add(new Data('Mar', 25));

 return data;
 }

// Wrapper class
public class Data {
public String name { get; set; }
public Integer data1 { get; set; }

public Data(String name, Integer data1) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data1 = data1;

 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's no documented way to handle Visualforce chart clicks; the various elements have handlers already that deal with highlighting, toggling values, etc. Instead, you'll want to research an alternative charting technology, such as [d3js](https://d3js.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "getting dynamic data of no. of contacts in each account"? Can you help me in dataset SOQL to be provide as input to dataset in chart.js/ d3.js or any hint would be great.

Comment: @MayankParnami `SELECT AccountId Id, COUNT(Id) numContacts FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN (...) GROUP BY AccountId` would give you the number of contacts per account.